# Why is my nth-of-type pseudo class not selecting the first a, and see it as the 4 one?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

My question is: Why is `.main-index a:nth-child(4)` working on my first `a` link, and not `.main-index a:nth-child(1)`?

I can't seem to find the problem or what i'm doing wrong.

It works but I know it isn't the right way to select the first one. 
Does anyone know how to select the first `a` in `.main-index` the right way

```css
.main-index h2 {
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "LemonMilk";
}


/********************************************
3.0 feedback
*********************************************/

.main-index p:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "NeueHaasGrotesk Light";
}

.main-index p:nth-of-type(2) {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-index img {
    margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
}

.main-index a:nth-child(4) {
    float: right;
    margin: 7px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #0e8f9c;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: "NeueHaasGrotesk medium";
}


/********************************************
5.0 Ticket Info International Student
*********************************************/

.main-index p:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.main-index a:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: #d3464e;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}


/********************************************
6.0 main content
*********************************************/

.background-home {
    background-image: url(../img/goingoutparadiso.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 80%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.background-home li {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-size: 50px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #3b3b3b;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.background-home a {
    display: block;
}

.background-home h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "NeueHaasGrotesk bold";
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #3b3b3b;
    border: 3px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline;
}

.background-home li:nth-child(1) {
    border-top: 0;
}

.background-home li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.background-home li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.background-home li:nth-child(4) {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-index">
        <h2>different spots</h2>
        <p>your feedback matters</p>
        <img alt="feedback page indicator" src="img/more-info-arrow-black.svg">
        <a href="feedback.html">feedback</a>
        <p>Just like every student, you as an international student can get discount in several clubs and bars in Amsterdam. This ticket will save you time and money!</p>
        <a href="https://www.tiqets.com/en/amsterdam-c75061/amsterdam-nightlife-clubs-free-drinks-p973786" target="_blank">Tickets for Amsterdam Nightlife &amp; Clubs + Free Drinks</a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="background-home">
                <li>
                    <a href="clubs.html"><h3>clubs</h3></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="bars.html"><h3>bars</h3></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href=""><h3>music</h3></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href=""><h3>festivals</h3></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info guys!! .main-index > a:nth-of-type(1) did the job.  Now I know more of selectors and how they work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.main-index a:nth-child(4) {}
```

You can use:

```
.main-index > a:nth-of-type(1) {}
```

---

You can read the difference about these pseudo-classes:

- [**`:nth-child()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

  > The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
  >   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
  >   or zero value for n, and has a parent element. More simply stated, the
  >   selector matches a number of child elements whose numeric position in
  >   the series of children matches the pattern an+b.
- [**`:nth-of-type()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

  > The :nth-of-type(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
  >   an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document
  >   tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent
  >   element. See :nth-child for a more thorough description of the syntax
  >   of its argument. This is a more flexible and useful pseudo selector if
  >   you want to ensure you're selecting the same type of tag no matter
  >   where it is inside the parent element, or what other different tags
  >   appear before it.
  >
  > ---

```css
.main-index h2 {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "LemonMilk";
}
/********************************************
3.0 feedback
*********************************************/

.main-index p:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "NeueHaasGrotesk Light";
}
.main-index p:nth-of-type(2) {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-index img {
  margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
}
.main-index > a:nth-of-type(1) {
  float: right;
  margin: 7px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #0e8f9c;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "NeueHaasGrotesk medium";
}
/********************************************
5.0 Ticket Info International Student
*********************************************/

.main-index p:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.main-index a:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: #d3464e;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
/********************************************
6.0 main content
*********************************************/

.background-home {
  background-image: url(../img/goingoutparadiso.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 80%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.background-home li {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #3b3b3b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.background-home a {
  display: block;
}
.background-home h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "NeueHaasGrotesk bold";
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #3b3b3b;
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline;
}
.background-home li:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: 0;
}
.background-home li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.background-home li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.background-home li:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-index">
  <h2>different spots</h2>
  <p>your feedback matters</p>
  <img alt="feedback page indicator" src="img/more-info-arrow-black.svg">
  <a href="feedback.html">feedback</a>
  <p>Just like every student, you as an international student can get discount in several clubs and bars in Amsterdam. This ticket will save you time and money!</p>
  <a href="https://www.tiqets.com/en/amsterdam-c75061/amsterdam-nightlife-clubs-free-drinks-p973786" target="_blank">Tickets for Amsterdam Nightlife &amp; Clubs + Free Drinks</a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="background-home">
      <li>
        <a href="clubs.html"><h3>clubs</h3></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="bars.html"><h3>bars</h3></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><h3>music</h3></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><h3>festivals</h3></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

---

The problem with using a lot of pseudo-classes is that if your markup changes, your CSS will break.

I recommend adding a class to the `<a>` element you want to add styles to instead of using a lot of pseudo-classes for the following reasons:

- Easier to maintain.
- Reusability *(You can use the same class on multiple elements.)*
- Styles won't break changing your markup.

Answer (score 3):

This is how `nth-child` works. That `<a>` element is the 4th *child* of your `main` element. The presense of the `a` selector in your selector sequence only ensures that the style only gets applied if the 4th child is an `<a>` element.

If you want to specifically single out `<a>` elements by their order, you can use `nth-of-type` instead, and specify that you want the 1st one:

```css
.main-index > a:nth-of-type(1) { ... }
```

> Does anyone know how to select the first `a` in `.main-index` the right way.

Personally I'd add an `id` or `class` attribute to your `<a>` element and select on that instead. That way if your HTML is ever modified to introduce new elements, your CSS won't stop working.

If for whatever reason you're unable to modify the HTML, but it's both the only link to point to your Feedback page and will *always* point to "feedback.html", you could alternatively use:

```css
a[href="feedback.html"] { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.main-index > a
```

this will target

```
<a href="https://www.tiqets.com/en/amsterdam-c75061/amsterdam-    nightlife-clubs-free-drinks-p973786" target="_blank">Tickets for Amsterdam     Nightlife &amp; Clubs + Free Drinks</a>
```

---

```
.main-index nav li:nth-child(1) a
```

this will target

```
<li>
    <a href="clubs.html"><h3>clubs</h3></a>
</li>
```

---

```
.main-index nav li:nth-child(2) a
```

this will target

```
<li>
    <a href="bars.html"><h3>bars</h3></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `.main-index a:nth-child(4)` working on my first a link,
>   and not `.main-index a:nth-child(1)`?

The `:nth-child(an + b)` pseudo class matches an element if it is the `an + b`th child of its parent (the expression is [explained here](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)). So:

```
.main-index a                 Matches all a elements inside .main-index

.main-index a:nth-child(4)    Matches all a elements inside .main-index that are
                              also the 4th child of their parent
                              It will match the feedback link

.main-index a:nth-child(1)    Matches all a elements inside .main-index that are
                              also the 1st child of their parent
                              It will match clubs, bars, ..., festivals links
```

Answer (score 0):

nth-child doesn't discriminate by element type. In your HTML the 4th child is your first a tag. Try using [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp).